# ¿Cómo modificar un valor de un vector de 10 valores pidiendo un valor y una posición por teclado?

Tags: java, array

Como puedo hacer un código que me permita ingresar 10 números enteros y después poner una posición y un valor modificarlo y después imprimir la matriz.

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
int[] ent = new int[10];
int num = 0;
    
    
for(int i=0; i<ent.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(">>> Da los valores de los vectores: ");
    num = teclado.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podrias intentar algo? que problema puntual tuviste?

Comment: Si tienes tu array debes introducirlos de acuerdo a su posición ent[posicion] = valor. para modificarlo es lo mismo, obten la posición y el valor a reemplazar

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente tienes que agregar los valores a tu array, lo puedes realizar en el mismo bucle:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ent.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(">>> Da los valores de los vectores: ");
        num = teclado.nextInt();
        
        //Almacena elementos en array
        ent[i] = num;
    }
```

Para modificar simplemente obtén la posición y reemplaza el valor de esa posición en el array con el nuevo valor.

```
    System.out.print(">>> Que posición deseas modificar? ");
    int position = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print(">>> Introduce el nuevo valor: ");
    int newValue = teclado.nextInt();
    //Se resta uno ya que las posiciones en el array inician desde 0.
    ent[position - 1] = newValue;
```

---

Este sería el ejercicio completo:

```
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] ent = new int[10];
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ent.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(">>> Da los valores de los vectores: ");
        num = teclado.nextInt();
        
        //Almacena elementos en array
        ent[i] = num;
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Valores en Array: " + Arrays.toString(ent));

    System.out.print(">>> Que posición deseas modificar? ");
    int position = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.print(">>> Introduce el nuevo valor: ");
    int newValue = teclado.nextInt();
    ent[position] = newValue;
    
    System.out.println("Valores en Array: " + Arrays.toString(ent));
```

---

```
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 10
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 11
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 12
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 14
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 15
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 18
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 20
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 22
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 24
>>> Da los valores de los vectores: 30

Valores en Array: [10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 30]
>>> Que posición deseas modificar? 3
>>> Introduce el nuevo valor: 100
Valores en Array: [10, 11, 100, 14, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 30]
```